# Query from two tables with one statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
User
-userid
-group
//other unrelated columns

Logs
-userid
-ip
```

What I want to do is using an IP query the Logs table for all userids and then get the groups of all the userids. Is this possible with a single query? If not is there anyway to speed it up other than querying every User row with the userid?

Comment: Please give use atleast those table CREATE statements, to see table structure.

Comment: No offense intended but this is the most basic of SQL questions possible. You can't learn such fundamentals on stackoverflow. Try an online course e.g. http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ip, userid, group
FROM Logs INNER JOIN User ON Logs.userid = User.userid
WHERE ip = '1.2.3.4'
```

Answer (score 3):

Surely this is a simple join?

```
select logs.userid,logs.ip,user.group
from logs
left join user on logs.userid=user.userid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct group 
from user u
join logs l on u.userid=l.userid
where l.ip='yourIP'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with a join ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html )

```
select User.group
from Logs
   inner join User on Logs.userid = User.userid
where Logs.ip = 'IP';
```

Answer (score 1):

At least back tick some of the field names that are keywords (group) or could be special (user)

```
SELECT L.`group`
FROM Logs L
INNER JOIN `User` U ON U.userid = L.userid
WHERE L.ip = '1.2.3.4'
GROUP BY L.`group`
```